# Prevent Filtering Edited record in extjs grid

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

I have extjs grid with cellediting, i have configured default filter on grid.
if user edits some records, i dont want that record getting filtered out(though they are part of filter criteria).

If user edits a records it becomes dirty, if record becomes dirty prevent filter being fired.

Especially i am using treegrid.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried to add `if(record.dirty) return true` to your filter functions?

Comment: can u share me how to do? where to add filter functions with sample

Comment: where and how you configurated the default filter?

Comment: while creating column configuration adding filter and its value like as follows   if 
     filter = {
      type: 'list', value : 2
     }